# Prebuilt electron module distribution

Tags: node.js, electron, node-pre-gyp

I'd like to distribute prebuilt binaries for a native Node.js add-on for Electron.

Presumably Node ABI changes between major bumps so I wonder if running `node-pre-gyp` with the right version of Node.js is gonna cut it or do I have to run `electron-rebuild` and publish rebuilt binaries?

A little experiment showed that node-pre-gyp couldn't find the compiled binary when running in electron environment. So it seems that `electron-rebuild` does something to patch that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I looked through the sources of `electron-builder` and found that it simply runs `install` on the package.

So having the following install hook is sufficient enough:

```
node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
```

I don't use `electron-rebuild` directly anymore since I produce the right binaries in the first place, but I run `electron-builder install-app-deps` which probably does similar.

I don't see any reason to bother with `prebuild` and `prebuild-install` at this point. It's two more dependencies that shield what `node-pre-gyp` and `node-gyp` both already implement.

I modified my script for travis to run builds for node and electron side by side:

```
# build for nodejs
- npm install --build-from-source

# build for electron
- npm install --build-from-source --runtime=electron --target=$ELECTRON_VERSION --dist-url=https://atom.io/download/atom-shell
```

Packaging step has to run twice with the same flags, i.e:

```
- if [[ "${TRAVIS_TAG}" != "" ]]; then npm run package --verbose; fi
- if [[ "${TRAVIS_TAG}" != "" ]]; then npm run package --runtime=electron --target=$ELECTRON_VERSION --verbose; fi
```

Both Travis and Appveyor support uploads to Github Releases or S3 so again no gain from using `prebuild` or `node-pre-gyp-github`, example for Travis:

```
deploy:
  provider: releases
  api_key:
    secure: ENCRYPTED_KEY
  file_glob: true
  file: build/stage/$PACKAGE_VERSION/*.tar.gz
  skip_cleanup: true
  on:
    tags: true
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `prebuild` to create prebuilt binaries for electron. We use it for `leveldown`.

https://github.com/prebuild/prebuild

Comment: Cool! And what do you use for your native binary, pure `node-gyp` or `node-pre-gyp`? I wonder because `npm install` will always install the dependencies for node and not electron. So I guess I still need to run `electron-rebuild` which is likely to copy the node binaries if they are available, is there any point to have binaries for electron at all then.

Comment: Correct! You still need `electron-rebuild` and it's still useful with prebuilt for `electron`. We have a demo example you can check out here https://github.com/Level/electron-demo

Comment: I had to dig into `electron-rebuild` a bit. It has support for `prebuild-install`, so if your module depends on and uses `prebuild-install`, then `electron-rebuild` will download prebuilt binaries instead of building them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It did help me to find the answer and figure out how that whole thing works. But I decided to stick to node-pre-gyp/node-gyp instruments.